# Number Theory: Relatively Prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Question #1

$5 \frac{15}{51} = \frac{a}{b}$ If a and b are relatively prime, find a+b.

Not sure my approach takes into consideration that a and b are relatively prime.

[image]

Comment: Please ask one question per post, and use Mathjax.

Comment: Does $5 \frac{15}{51} = 5 + \frac{15}{51} $ or $5 \cdot \frac{15}{51}$ ?

Comment: good question, the book shows it as the first i would i assume the third though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem 1 just asks to put $\frac{15}{51}$ into reduced form, so that the numerator and denominator don't share a common factor. 
$$
\frac{15}{51} =\frac{5}{17}=\frac{a}{b}
$$
So $a+b=\ldots$

Problem 2 is trickier.  Let's see how large we could make $x+y+z$.  TO do that, we want to stuff as much as possible into $x$ since the product grows faster if there are more $y$ or $z$.

Well, $y$ and $z$ have to be at least $1$ so we already have a factor of $15$.  In that case, 
$$ 5000/15 = 333\frac13 \leq  2^x \implies x > 8 \\
 6000/15 = 400 \geq  2^x \implies x < 9 
$$
So that would not work.

Your approach is pretty good but somewhare along the line you have goofed because $2^23^25^3 = 4500$ is not in the correct range.  You could try tweaking it upward by replacing $2$ factors of $5$ by five factors of $2$, since $32>25$.  Then
$$
2^73^25^1 = 5760
$$
So one possible value of $x+y+z$ is ten.  Still no joy, that is not in the list.

Let's get more systematic:  Start with the maximum of four factors of 5, then three, then two, ... and see where that gets us.
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} 5^43^12^1 = 3750 &  5^43^12^2 = 7500 & \mbox{bad} \\
 5^33^22^2 = 4500&  5^33^22^3 = 9000 & \mbox{bad} \\
 5^33^122^3 = 3000 &  5^33^12^4 = 6000 & \mbox{bad} \\
5^23^42^1 = 4050 & 5^23^42^2  = 8100& \mbox{bad} \\
5^23^32^3 = 5400 & 8 \mbox{ is on list} & \mbox{good!} \\
5^23^22^4 = 3600 & 5^23^22^5 = 7200& \mbox{bad} \\
5^23^12^6 = 4800& 5^23^12^7  = 9600& \mbox{bad} \\
\end{array}
$$
 I'm not going to bother with $5^1$ expressions because we have already found the answer, which is $x+y+z=8$.